# getchar behaviour at netbeans IDE

Tags: c, netbeans

Compiling this code with netbeans 6.8 C++ (mingw)

```
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        printf("\r\ntest");
    }

    getchar();
```

It don't print one hundred times the "test" word..

It just execute the getchar() prior the printf loop

It's a netbeans problem, because it executes trough c:\msys\1.0\bin\sh.exe

obviously if I try it with command line it works right

why? anyone knows how to solve it? thanks

Comment: Random stab in the dark: try `fflush(stdout)` prior to `getchar()`.

Comment: @Heath Hunnicutt, you've kill the bug with that stab, I thing the code get ugly if I have to search every printf to add fflush(stdout) but it's a way

Comment: Some environments flush buffers at newlines. You might only have to add the fflush(stdout) to printfs that don't end with '\n'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to move the answer from comments to answer, but as a Community Wiki.  I wouldn't want to write some "pseudo-definitive" answer which was really a stab in the dark, as this is.

Based on the symptom of output not appearing on the terminal, I suggested that you add `fflush(stdout)` prior to the `getchar()` call.  The `fflush()` is a standard C library function which "flushes" pending output or input.

I just guessed that your `printf()` output was going into a buffer and that calling `fflush(stdout)` would cause that buffer to be sent to the terminal, solving your symptom.

You could possibly use the following macro and variadic function to allow that you will `fflush` after every `printf`:

```
/*
 * If the environment supplies vfprintf():
 */
#define printf    my_printf

int my_printf(const char * fmt, ...)
{
    int ret_val;
    va_list var_args;

    va_start(var_args, fmt);
    ret_val = vfprintf(stdout, fmt, var_args);
    va_end(var_args);

    fflush(stdout);

    return ret_val;
}
```

otherwise maybe:

```
/* If the environment lacks vfprintf() */
#define my_printf(args)  ((void)printf args, (void)fflush(stdout))

/*
 * Usage:
 * 
 * my_printf(("Format %s\r\n", "string"));
 *
 */
```

Comment: that solves it, but I was waiting some solution from netbeans IDE side, or something, change all my source is the last thing to try =)

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing the terminal where the program is shown and it works fine

Right click the project you are working  -> properties -> run -> " Console type " set it to external

And the field below it called " External Terminal type " to the terminal of your os.

Now it will work fine :)